How do I tell a powerline apart from other wires?
I would like to be able to tell what is a powerline and what is not. Browsing on panoramax, I encountered the following scene in Saint-Martin-Terressus, France:

On the left side of the road, I can recognise the powerline (marked it with a blue box). It is even mapped on OpenStreetMap:

However, I am unsure on what's on the right side of the road (marked with a red box).
How do I tell whether what's on the right side of the road is a powerline or not?
I am worried it might be a telephone cable or someting similar.

it probably is a telephone cable. How do I know? Mostly by the fact that there's another line that is unambigously a power line on the other side. (and, the small grey box on the mast is a strong indication) It's going to be hard to figure that out without context, just from pictures.

It hurts if you touch it.

why are you worried that it might be a telephone cable?

I don't want to map it as a powerline in OSM if it's a telephone cable.

There are a couple of clues.

Overhead power lines are usually uninsulated as air provides adequate insulation for free. That means that the number of conductors is > 1 and there is spacing between them.
Overhead powerlines use insulators on the cable suspension points.
The cable on the right has a (likely steel) catenary wire carrying the cable and that is connected directly to the steel bracket on the pole.
There is a coil of "cable" hanging on the pole. This suggests fiber-optic cable which is often seen in this configuration where I live in Ireland. I suspect that they like to make all the joints in properly sealed boxes as the fiber joins take more care and precision compared to twisted pair copper and a little excess might come in handy during repairs.

I'd say fiber telecom cable.

#1 is not universally true. Almost all overhead 1kV and less in Norway is insulated. I would say #4 is the by far most reliable indicator; no-one would splice power cable in that way.

@vidarlo, "usually uninsulated" is universally true (when taking Norway as part of the whole world). I've been on this site long enough to give myself some wriggle room! Thanks for the feedback.

I totally agree with you. Re #4 - with fiber you generally care less about losses, so you provide spare length. Cheap 10$ modules are capable of 100km on single mode fiber. 50m extra simply doesn't matter to your link budget. With a power cable a splice would be made at line height and with less spare cable.

To add to @vidarlo, by length, most US overhead power lines are insulated. It's uneconomical to run 3 separate drops between a pole and a building, so line-voltage live wires are insulated and twisted around the neutral. And it's most because my local power company reports they maintain about 2x more miles of drop wiring than overhead distribution which is 10x more than transmission.

This is easy. The pole on the left, equipped with bare three-phase lines on insulators, is part of the POCO AC distribution system. The pole on the right outfitted with a single insulated cable and an inline CATV repeater, is clearly for CATV. What you see is typical of rural distribution.
Regarding power in CATV or TELCO Coax and fiber systems, DC power is delivered via the coax shield and center conductor. In the case of fiber, the power runs through a pair of copper conductors within the hybrid cable. To minimize voltage losses and maintain a low current, high-voltage DC is utilized.
So, if you are worried about it being Telecom...

Given the amplifier box on the pole on the right, that looks like communications - coax or fiber. Either coax or fiber can have power bundled within, or the amp may be powered from the customer premises. I’m not sure how they normally would do it in France. Someone with local expertise would need to pitch in.

Google Streetview in September 2022 shows the same pole on the right, but without the loop of cable or the box mounted on the pole.  There is still a small wire that loops over the top of the pole and catenary wires to hold it in tension.
I'm not familiar with what's happening in Haute Vienne at that time, but I would assume this is a fibre installation that's happened some time between Sep 2022 and Sep 2023.  Previously there was a copper phone cable, and in that time somebody has installed fibre along the same pole run.  The grey box is a fibre splice and the loop is a pre-made fibre that's been spliced on to the fibre along the pole run.  Effectively this is a tee to the fibre run that will drop a fibre for a local connection, but the loop of cable suggests it doesn't go anywhere yet.
It's not immediately clear why though - there are houses around the corner with a similar drop but no obvious premises here. It may be the fibre company is putting in a drop for every piece of land even if it doesn't currently have a house on it, perhaps as a condition of installation.
